# Is it possible to match against a NULL pointer in Rust?

Tags: pointers, rust

Calling `is_null()` feels a bit odd:

```
fn do_stuff(ptr: *const i32) -> Option<i32> {
    if ptr.is_null() {
        None
    } else {
        Some(do_transform(*ptr, 42))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of Rust 1.9, there's a [function `as_ref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.as_ref) that converts a raw pointer to an `Option<&T>`, and a mutable variant [`as_mut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.as_mut):

Your code would look something like

```
fn do_stuff(ptr: *const i32) -> Option<i32> {
    let ptr = unsafe { ptr.as_ref() };
    ptr.map(|x| do_transform(x, 42))
}
```

Comment: 1.9 has been released just now and stabilized `as_ref` and `as_mut`

Comment: @delnan I think that's a record. 30 minutes after I post my answer, it's out of date because the language itself updated... And I *definitely* checked the docs to see that it was unstable! ^_^

Comment: It's also a record the other way around: Florian asked a question, and 30 min later the functionality is implemented and stable :D