# How to convert a raw pointer, which can be null, into an Option?

Tags: pointers, rust, option-type, nullable

I wrote the following macro:

```
macro_rules! ptr_to_opt {
    ($p: expr) => {
        if $p.is_null() {
            None
        } else {
            Some($p)
        }
    };
}
```

That allows me to check raw pointers in a `match`:

```
match ptr_to_opt!(myRawPtr) {
    Some(ptr) => { ... },
    None      => { ... },
}
```

Is there any built-in feature to replace my `ptr_to_opt` macro?

---

EDIT:

This question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37466676/6923555) in the sense that `as_ref` converts the pointer into a reference, while I want to keep the pointer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to match against a NULL pointer in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466676/is-it-possible-to-match-against-a-null-pointer-in-rust)

Comment: "This question is different from this one in the sense that as_ref converts the pointer into a reference, while I want to keep the pointer." you can just cast the reference back to a pointer after it's done its job, although this is UB if the pointer is be dangling, or to uninitialised memory.

Comment: @Masklinn Then using `ptr_to_opt` is a cleaner option, since there's no casting involved. And we're back to the beginning of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 5 months, I found two different solutions to this problem.

**First:** Using the [as_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.as_mut) method of the raw pointer. In the `Ok` a reference is returned instead of the pointer, but in some cases a reference can be implicitly converted to a pointer, so it works in some situations.

**Second:** The function below:

```
use std::ffi::c_void;

pub fn ptr_as_opt(ptr: *mut c_void) -> Option<*mut c_void> {
    if ptr.is_null() {
        None
    } else {
        Some(ptr)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [`NonNull::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html#method.new) to get an `Option<NonNull<T>>` from a `*mut T`. If you just want an `Option<*mut T>` (which you probably shouldn't need considering `NonNull` can do just about everything a pointer can), then you can map it with [`NonNull::as_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html#method.as_ptr).